# Any way to get check if mail is delivered or not?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using java mail api to send mail,i need to check whether mail is delivered properly or not and if mail is not sent,need to send again,can anyone help me in solving this?

Comment: I don't know much about this, but I'm sure the API answers this.

Comment: You can't. Once an email is sent, you will need to read the mail server of the recipient to see if they actually received it. Email sending is not a bi-directional communication.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check whether the mail is received by other person or not. But you can ensure that u'r mail have sent properly by checking sentbox of your account.

Here is the way to check if you're using gmail

```
Folder outbox = store.getFolder(”[Gmail]/Sent Mail”);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `delivered` and `sent` are two different things.

Delivered means the email is reached to recipient and sent means sent from your side.

So if you need to track whether that email is sent or not you don't have to do anything special. You will get appropriate error message if message sending is failed. So you can trigger an exception and do stuff to send message again. Or you can check it from your sent box using javamail if you want.

If you need to know whether message is delivered or not, then you will probably need to use third party api, which mostly uses hidden images to track whether email is viewed or not.(read receipt).